# Find $99^{101103} \bmod 101$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find $99^{101103} \bmod 101$.

The solution doesn't make any sense to me for this. They use Fermat's Little Theorem. Also used the fact that $101$ is prime, $a^{100} = 1 \text{ mod } 101$

$$99^{101103} = 99^{101100} \cdot 99^3 = (99^{100})^{1011} \cdot 99^3 \equiv 1^{1011}\cdot (-2)^3 \equiv -8 \equiv 93 \ (\text{ mod } 101\ ).$$

I don't understand how they got $(99^{100})^{1011} \rightarrow 1^{1011}$ and where did the $(-2)^3 $ come from?

Comment: $99^{100}\equiv 1 \pmod {101}$ (FLT). $99 \equiv -2 \pmod {101}$.

Comment: Why is it $-2 ( \text{ mod } 101)? $

Comment: $99 - 101 = -2$. Use `\pmod`.

Comment: What does Fermat's little theorem say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall the fact that $a^{100} \equiv 1 \pmod{101}$ (provided that $a$ is not divisible by $101$).

Let $a = 99.$

Also $99 \equiv -2 \pmod{101},$
because $-2 = 99 - 101.$